# Asymptotic behavior of the number of idempotent maps

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For every $n\ge1$, let us denote by $q_n$ the number of maps $f:\lbrack\!\lbrack1,n\rbrack\!\rbrack\to\lbrack\!\lbrack1,n\rbrack\!\rbrack$ such that $f\circ f=f$.

I have obtained the following closed form :

$$q_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}k^{n-k}$$

Computation of $\displaystyle{\frac{q_n}{n^n}}$ provides numerical evidence that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q_n}{n^n}=0}$.

I tried to prove it but didn't succeed ...

A more interesting and probably less simple question would be to compute an equivalent of $q_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Just showing that $\dfrac{q_n}{n^n} \to 0$ isn't very hard once one stops looking for more precise estimates:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^{n-k}
&= \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k \leqslant n/2} \binom{n}{k} k^{n-k} + \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k > n/2} \binom{n}{k} k^{n-k} \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{n^n} \sum_{k \leqslant n/2} \binom{n}{k} \biggl(\frac{n}{2}\biggr)^{n-k} + \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{k > n/2} \binom{n}{k} n^{n/2} \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k \leqslant n/2} \binom{n}{k}\biggl(\frac{2}{n}\biggr)^k + \frac{1}{n^{n/2}} \sum_{k > n/2} \binom{n}{k} \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{2^n}\biggl(1 + \frac{2}{n}\biggr)^n + \frac{2^n}{n^{n/2}} \\
&< \frac{e^2}{2^n} + \biggl(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\biggr)^n.
\end{align}

Finding the asymptotic behaviour of $q_n$ seems difficult. It's not even easy to find the largest term in the sum. Some quick-and-dirty estimates say that the largest terms occur when $k$ is about $n/\log n$, and that would suggest

$$\log q_n = n(\log n - \log \log n - 1) + o(n)$$

if I haven't made a mistake in my scribblings, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Nice computation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is sequence A00358 in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000248). A detailed analysis of the asymptotic behaviour of $q_n$ can be found in [1].

[1] B. Harris and L. Schoenfeld, [The number of idempotent elements in symmetric semigroups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980067800024?via%3Dihub), *J. Combin. Theory*, **3** (1967), 122-135.